# Wamp incorrect server date after changing .ini file to correct format?

Tags: php, wamp

In my php.ini I have changed the timezone to Europe/London.

Although the date still echo at

2028/08/11

The time is correct though, how is this and how can I correct it.

Comment: What does your PHP date format look like? Post the code you are using to echo that date. It looks like there is an hour (20) next to the correct date (28/08/11).

Comment: Like this, date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time()")

Comment: That last quotation shouldn't be there, but that's probably a typo. Are you echoing anything else on the page?

Comment: My bad... It was how mysql was saving it and then the echo error was the result, thanks for your help, if you want to answer I will mark you up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result:

`2028/08/11`

contains the correct date, but has a `20` appended to the beginning. If your date formatting is correct, you or another operation must be echoing `20`.

As stated in your comment, this was the result of a MySQL error.